# SQL-How to select an example with a given set of options and values

Tags: sql, select

i want to get the quantity of examples which have the same options with equal values  
Here are the tables    
table: ExampleOption

```
--------------
| id | nom   |
--------------
| 1  | size  |
--------------
| 2  | color |
--------------
```

table: Value

```
------------------------------------------
| Example_id | ExampleOption_id | value  |
------------------------------------------
| 1          |       1          | XL     |
------------------------------------------
| 1          |       2          | black  |
------------------------------------------
| 2          |       1          |  L     |
------------------------------------------
| 2          |       2          | red    |
------------------------------------------
| 3          |       1          | XL     |
------------------------------------------
| 3          |       2          | red    |
------------------------------------------
```

table: Example

```
---------------------------------
|     id     | product_id       |
--------------------------------- 
| 1          |        1         |
---------------------------------
| 2          |        1         |
---------------------------------
| 3          |       2          |
---------------------------------
```

i tried this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Example_id) FROM Value WHERE 
Example_id IN(SELECT id FROM Example WHERE product_id=1)
AND ( ExampleOption_id = 1 AND value = 'XL' OR ExampleOption_id = 2 AND value='red')
```

this query should return 2 but it returns 3 which wrong as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, I believe your `OR` statement in your `WHERE` criteria is causing the incorrect results.  Try adding some parentheses:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT exemplaire_id) 
FROM valeur 
WHERE exemplaire_id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM produit 
    WHERE produit_id=?) 
    AND ((option_produit_id = 1 AND valeur = 'XL') 
         OR (option_produit_id = 2 AND valeur='red'))
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94cb4/3)

Comment: it doesn't work either, i'm getting the same result back

Comment: @user3674138 -- this returns 2 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94cb4/3) -- but again, hard to tell depending on the `produit_id` you choose.

Comment: produit_id is product_id now, anyway
i'm passing 1 as product_id

Comment: @user3674138 -- please update my fiddle and let me know how it isn't working.

Comment: here we go [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8042/1)
we've got one example with size=XL and color=red
and the result is 2

Comment: @user3674138 -- still not following.  This returns a count of 2 which appears to be correct.  Example Id 1 is returned because it matches 1 and XL and 2 is returned because it matches 2 and red...

Comment: yes you're right the result is correct according to the query, 
but as i mentioned above, the result i want to get back is '1'
(cause we have only one example with size=XL & color=red).

Comment: @user3674138 -- here you go.  think I finally understand: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7ef7/7.  You need to use `group by` in a subquery with `count`.

Comment: thanks a lot, but according to your insert statements, there are 2 examples which have size=XL and color=red, the first example has an id=2 and the second has in id=3, which means that the expected result is '2' and not '1', so it's not correct.

Comment: @user3674138 -- your first part of your where criteria is removing id `3` as an option since it's not related to product id 2...

Comment: yes that's right, as far as i understood in this part of the query `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ExampleOption_id) = 2`
the number'2' represent the number of options ?
which could be calculated like this 
`(select count(ExampleOption_id) from value where Example_id IN(select id from Exemple WHERE product_id = 1))`

Comment: it's working very well thanks a lot, 
this is the final query : 
    `SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
      SELECT Example_id 
      FROM Value
      WHERE ((ExampleOption_id = 1 AND value = 'XL') OR 
             (ExampleOption_id = 2 AND value='black'))
      GROUP BY Example_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ExampleOption_id) = 
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ExampleOption_id) FROM value WHERE
    Example_id IN
       (SELECT id FROM Example WHERE product_id = 1))
    ) t
    WHERE t.Example_id IN (SELECT id FROM example WHERE product_id
    = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for something like this (untested code!)

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT Example_id)
FROM
  Value V
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Example E WHERE V.Example_id = E.id AND E.product_id = 1)
  AND (
    (V.ExampleOption_id = 1 AND V.value = 'XL')
    OR (V.ExampleOption_id = 2 AND V.value = 'red')
  )
GROUP BY
  V.Example_id
HAVING
  COUNT(1) = 2
```

Group your result, then filter to all groups which has all the two records.
(The `DISTINCT` could be unnecessary)